# How to prevent dehydratedState overwrite when using in Higher Order Component in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I am facing a problem when dehydrating data to SSR in custom HOC, Specifically, I want to hydrate two keys `test1` and `test2` from server to client to support SSR but I'm getting undefined value returned from `test1`. I think the reason is because the dehydratedState was overwrited. How do I fix this problem?

My code here:

```
const withHOC = (gssp) => async (context) => {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery('test1', () => 'abc123');
    const childProps = await gssp(context);

    return {
        props: {
            dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
            ...(childProps.props ? childProps.props : {}),
        },
    };
};

export const getServerSideProps = withHOC(async context => {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery('test2', () => 'profile-example-data');

    return {
        props: {
            dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
        },
    };
});


// when trying test to get data in component:

queryClient.getQueryData('test1'); // undefined
queryClient.getQueryData('test2'); // profile-example-data
```

Comment: It is not clear to me why you're instantiating two different query clients here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The props have the same name `dehydratedState`, so they overwrite each other. This is not a problem of react-query, but of the getServerSideProps composition.

My best guess on why you wanted to split it into two functions is because there are some pages where you only need `'test1'`, and other pages where you'd want to "enhance" that to prefetch `'test1'` and `'test2'`.

If that's the case, I would either just duplicate the logic or extract just the prefetching part, but not the whole "getServerSideProps" part, to a reusable function. It should also use the same `queryClient` because that's where the data goes that you'd want to dehydrate just once:

```
export const prefetchTest1 = (queryClient) => queryClient.prefetchQuery('test1', () => 'abc123');

export const getServerSideProps = async context => {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    await prefetchTest1(queryClient)
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery('test2', () => 'profile-example-data');

    return {
        props: {
            dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
        },
    };
};
```

Comment: You are my life saver. Thank you from the bottom of my heart for everything! @TkDodo